# Extending Wightman axioms to gauge theories

Tags: quantum-field-theory, gauge-theory, wightman-fields

I understand that Wightman axioms were defined for scalar quantum field theories. However, what prevents axiomatization of non-scalar quantum field theories, such as gauge theories, even for free field?

Comment: Related https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/92471/226902 https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/324212/226902

Answer (score 3):

Well, nothing prevents a generalization of Wightman's axioms in case of free gauge theories. This, however, requires in turn a generalization of Hilbert spaces, known as [Krein Spaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indefinite_inner_product_space). The only lucid and thorough presentation I know of is Chapter #10 of [BLOT](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/079230540X). I hope this boook is available to you.

Answer (score 1):

As @DanielC Pointed out, Krein spaces are the main ingredient to generalise Wightman axioms to free gauge theories. There is a framework, which you might be looking for: the Strocchi Wightman framework. You can find a detailed description in chapter 7 of the following notes:

https://www-m5.ma.tum.de/foswiki/pub/M5/Allgemeines/WojciechDybalski/Notes-QFT41.pdf