# What is the field map in 0+1-dimensional QFT?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, wightman-fields

I'm a beginner trying to learn something about the Wightman axioms. I got the idea that from an abstract Hilbert space and an abstract Hamiltonian operator, I should be able to produce a trivial example of a "0+1-dimensional Wightman quantum field theory," but so far I haven't seen this spelled out.

Two bullet points on what I can see or guess, and one question:

- Part of the Wightman axioms is a representation of the Poincare group on a Hilbert space. In 0+1 dimensions, the Poincare group is just time evolution. So our Hilbert space and $\exp(iHt)$ gives this part of the Wightman axioms.
- Part of the Wightman axioms is a vacuum vector. This must be the ground state of $H$.

Here's my question:

- Part of the Wightman axioms is a "field map." This is something like the data of operators $\phi(t)$ on the Hilbert space for each point $t$ in spacetime (= time, in $0+1$ dimensions). What are these operators supposed to be, in terms of the Hamiltonian? I got stuck trying to guess.

Comment: Nice question. You may find this interesting: [Why is quantum mechanics called 0+1 dimensional QFT?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/361856/226902). Also related: [Where do the Wightman axioms fit in QFT?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/324212/226902)

Answer (score 0):

My view now is that the field map is additional information, not determined by the Hilbert space and Hamiltonian.

Wightman axioms imply the formula $\phi(t) = \exp(iHt) \phi(0)\exp(-iHt)$ holds, so the field map is determined by the operator $\phi(0)$. Or if there is more than one kind of field $\phi_1,\phi_2,\ldots$, then it is determined by the operators $\phi_1(0),\phi_2(0),\ldots$. No reason for these observables to be determined by the Hamiltonian $H$.

Example: If there is just one scalar field taking values in $\mathbf{R}$, then the Hilbert space is $L^2(\mathbf{R})$. The operator $\phi(0)$ is supposed to measure the strength of the field at time $0$ (and at the unique point of 0-dimensional space), i.e. it is the "position" operator on $L^2(\mathbf{R})$.

Corrections welcome!